How to run sudo apt update in Xampp, windows
I am going to do workout about Build a PWA Storefront for Magento 2 in Xampp windows platform, how to perform following command,
sudo apt update
Source : https://onilab.com/blog/how-to-build-a-pwa-storefront-magento-2-a-detailed-guide

Hi @zus, sudo and apt are meant for Linux operating systems. To install and configure react js in Windows systems, you will need to follow instructions for Windows.

The sudo apt update command is a Linux/Debian system administration command that updates the list of available packages.

After Magento installation, you have to
clone the PWA Studio repository
git clone https://github.com/magento-research/pwa-studio.git
Then you have to install yarn.
yarn install
, then
Specify the Magento backend server in .env file. you can see the .env.dist file in
/var/www/html/mage0/pwa-studio/packages/venia-concept/directory. If you are not
able see, enable show hidden files. Now create .env file from this env. dist
cp packages/venia-concept/.env.dist packages/venia-concept/.env
Open this .env file and find MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL. Here configure your
local Magento 2.3 instance, in my case it is:
MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL="https://mgpwa2-pwa.com/"
Then
Generate SSL certificate because PWA features require an HTTPS Secure Domain. From the root directory of PWA (/pwa-studio) run the below command:
Yarn build pack create-custom-origin packages/venia-concept
Now let's install sample data for venia-theme to make it good-looking.
Find the deployVeniaSampleData.sh file in
/var/www/html/mage0/pwa-studio/packages/venia-concept/ directory. And copy this
file in your Magento root directory. Now it must look like
/var/www/html/mage0/deployVeniaSampleData.sh Now run:
Bash deployVeniaSampleData.sh
After successful installation run:
bin/magento setup: upgrade
Now go back to PWA-studio directory /var/www/html/mage0/pwa-studio and
start the Server.
Yarn run build
